# How to use a foreach loop with project deployment model

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis

I have a SSIS project that is configured to project deployment model, within this I have two connections one for a flat file and one for a sql db. Both connections are in project mode. Now I want to use a foreach loop container to go through a folder of files to import them into the sql db. Within the for each loop container I can only create a variable on the user level for the file names. Using this variable in an expression for the file connection is not possible since the connection requires a project variable. How can the foreach loop container be used in a project deployment model ?